# php get date a week ago

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to create a selector for elements that are within a week old. i get a timestamp like this `Sun, 02 Jun 2013 22:05:00 GMT` but the selector should not be affected by time

E.G.

```
<?

$curdate = date( 'D, d M Y H:I:s' );
$olddate = "Sun, 02 Jun 2013 22:05:00 GMT";

if($curdate < $olddate){
    // Date is with in a week
} else {
    // Date is older then a week
}
```

But in this case, it should not be affected by the time online by the day. But i can't get it working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate and get a date in the past (e.g. 3 weeks ago) from today's date (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575364/how-to-calculate-and-get-a-date-in-the-past-e-g-3-weeks-ago-from-todays-date)

Comment: No, @vascowhite, this question is how to compare the date within a week!

Comment: The point is that the answer there also answers your question, hence it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only create a date out of the compariondate. After that you should create a timestamp of the given date `Sun, 02 Jun 2013 22:05:00 GMT`, and that should be converted to a datestring with only the date. And then you create another timestamp out of that....

If you know what i mean... This should work:

```
<?php
    // First create the date

    $date = 'Sun, 02 Jun 2013 22:05:00 GMT';

    // To a timestamp
    $t_date = strtotime($date);

    // Noew remove the seconds: First create a new date, with a timestamp of the give date.
    // After that create a datestring with only the date
    $date = date("jS F Y", $t_date);
    // And create a new timestamp
    $t_date = strtotime($date);

    // One week back: time - 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 7 days * -1 to get backwards
    // And we only create a date of this
    $weekback = date('jS F Y', time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * -7) );
    // Create a timestamp
    $t_weekback = strtotime($weekback);

    // Debug
    echo "Date: $date<br/>Date (UTC): $t_date<br/>";
    echo "Last week: $weekback<br/>Last week (UTC): $t_weekback<br/>";

    if ($t_date <= $t_weekback) {
        //Date is older then a week
        echo "Outside a week: last week($t_date) <= The date($t_weekback)";
    }else{
         //Date is within a week
         echo "Within a week: $t_date > $t_weekback";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 47):

PHP's `strtotime()` function is what your looking for.

For example:

```
echo date('jS F Y H:i.s', strtotime('-1 week'));
```

You can feed in a number of different string's into the `strtotime()` function such as:

```
strtotime('yesterday');
strtotime('-2 days ago');
strtotime('+5 days');
```

Comment: Thank you! But i used xvilo's answer!

Comment: @xvilo but this answer is one line of code.  much more sustainable, faster.  I would only add maybe set timezone, e.g. date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); Suppose the user is working late at night and the server is on a different time zone than the user.  If they aren't aware of the server's alternate time zone, they could be generating inaccurate data, for instance pulling sales reports.

Comment: @Jason a bit late to the party? This question is from 2013!

Comment: @xvilo necroposting is a thing!

Comment: @Jason > Usually by new, inexperienced members of the board.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using PHP >= 5.3 you could use the following:

```
<?php

$date     = new DateTime('Sun, 02 Jun 2013 22:05:00 GMT');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');

if(new DateTime() < $date->add($interval)){
    //date is with in a week
}{
    //date is older then a week
}
```

Comment: For some kind of reason i get this: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct() [<a href='dateinterval.--construct'>dateinterval.--construct</a>]: Unknown or bad format (PT1W)' in /home/xvilo/*****/jonginnopmail.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /home/xvilo/*****/jonginnopmail.php(24): DateInterval->__construct('PT1W') #1 /home/xvilo/*****/jonginnopmail.php(717): getFeed('http://jonginno...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/xvilo/*****/jonginnopmail.php on line 24

Comment: My mistake. It has to read 'P1W' instead of 'PT1W'. I've already changed the answer

Comment: Ah, Allright, Well thank you! But xvilo's answer was working!

Comment: Fine with me. Beware of issues with DST though, as the day/week-length is hardcoded and does not take DST-Changes into account. But it might not be an issue in your case.